# How to join using embedded links in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

given a similar schema for people as:

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Darth",
  "family": [2,3]
},
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Luke"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Leia"
  }
]
```

how do I return Darth and outer join to get all his family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want the ids in `family` to be replaced with the documents for the family members, you can do a `map` with a `get`.

Like this:

```
r.table('people').get(1) // Get Darth
  // Add a `family` property to Darth
  .merge(function (row) {
    return {
      // Map all the family member ids to their respective documents
      'family': row('family').map(function (id) {
        return r.table('people').get(id);
      })
    }
  })
```

The result of this query will be something this:

```
{
  "family": [
    {
      "id": 2 ,
      "name":  "Luke"
    } ,
    {
      "id": 3 ,
      "name":  "Leia"
    }
  ] ,
  "id": 1 ,
  "name":  "Darth"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge. Will this result in a join within rethink or separate queries fired off within the function for the merge? Kinda OK when fetching a single doc, but could be disastrous when not using get(1) like a SELECT n+1 query

Comment: These are point reads on an indexed field, so the performance should actually be pretty good. Obviously it depends on how many documents you are doing and how many sub-documents, each one of your documents is getting. If you post more background info on what you're trying to accomplish, I might be able to help you out a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with the below which will be much more performant than a map I believe. And it will use the default index on id

```
r.db('myDb')
    .table('tests')
    .get(1)
  .merge(function (person) {
    return {
      myFamily: r.db('myDb').table('tests').getAll(r.args(person('family'))).coerceTo('ARRAY')
    }
  })
  .pluck('name', 'myFamily');
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the difference between this and a `map` with `get` is negligible, since they're pretty much both indexed operations and with `getAll`, the database has to traverse the B-Tree several times anyways when doing these point reads. For very large tables, it might be faster to use `getAll`, but it probably won't be much of a difference.

Comment: Keep in mind, that these queries are being executed completely in the database, which means that in the database, the operations for `getAll` is not that different from a `map` and `get` and because you sent the whole query at once it doesn't have to take several round trips to execute the query.